# Identify Google user from third party web application

Tags: java, php, android, web, oauth-2.0

I'm developing an Android application that connects to a web service written in PHP and saves/retrieves some user information.

I need a way to securely identify users of that application on the web server. I can easily use `AccountManager` to retrieve user email and send it to the web server, but what is the simplest way to authenticate it?

My web service doesn't use any Google services/APIs. The only thing that I need is to confirm (on web server side) that `user@gmail.com` is really `user@gmail.com`.